# Old version of Parity stopped working and I'm unable to install new stable version

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

I have parity 1.6.8 installed on OSX 10.13.6

Parity used to work by running to .app file and then accessing http://127.0.0.1:8180/#/home on a web browser.

Now it tells me, "Unable to make a connection to the Parity Secure API. To update your secure token or to generate a new one, run (parity signer new-token) and paste the generated token into the space below."

I open Terminal and type in parity signer new-token  but returns

-bash: parity: command not found

I go to https://www.parity.io/ethereum/#download to download the stable version of Parity but when I double click on it opens up my text editor with a bunch of code in it without installing the app.

How can I get Parity going again? I'd also like to be able to prevent Parity from downloading the blockchain when I start it.

My objective is to check to see if a wallet I created on parity a while ago has any funds in it.

Comment: "
If you have forgotten your passwords or can't find your key files, but you remember your seed-phrase, you can use a legacy version of MEW. (grab the parity-enabled zip, extract it somewhere, open index.html, go to the "view wallet info" page, and after you use your parity phrase to unlock, you'll be able to grab your private key to import into other wallet software)
" This would have been perfect. Unfortunately I just tried and the linked version of MEW generates a different wallet address to what I have in Parity Signer. So I'm not sure which derivation path has been taken by parity and how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Parity has dropped support for the UI in favor of focusing on the core node - if you want the kind of experience that you were used to with the old "Parity App", you should consider moving to one of the [alternatives](https://github.com/parity-js/shell#parity-ui-alternatives).

Here's some information that might help you migrate:

The default data directory on OSX is: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/`

If you dig around in the "keys" folder (there might be additional keys folders in the different "chains" folders) you will be able to find your json key files which you can import into the wallet of your choice (I hope you remember your password)

If you have forgotten your passwords or can't find your key files, but you remember your seed-phrase, you can use a [legacy version](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/tag/v3.9.0) of MEW.

(grab the parity-enabled zip, extract it somewhere, open index.html, go to the "view wallet info" page, and after you use your parity phrase to unlock, you'll be able to grab your private key to import into other wallet software)